# Maybe: Contact pictures

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this question.  On an iphone, when I get a "Maybe: Contact" text message, there is often an a profile picture already attached to the person.  Though I understand where the "maybe:" comes from (an older text, email, contact, my phone is smart enough to have found etc.), I can't understand where on earth the accompanying contact picture comes from.  I didn't set it and I've never seen some of them that have come in for my friends (meaning, I don't think it was from Facebook).  For example:  my insurance guy came in on a text as a maybe and he had a contact picture attached of him fishing. Where did it find that?  Is that a picture set up on HIS phone, or did it pull from somewhere else?  Anyone have any idea?  It's making me crazy.

Comment: iOS 13 allows text senders to [specify an iMessage profile picture](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-set-an-imessage-profile-picture-and-name-in-ios-13/) which apparently overrides your contact picture, and also displays a profile pic from the sender if you don't have a contact. Perhaps this is coming into play?

Comment: That actually helps a great deal - thank you so much for taking the time to respond!